# How can i ignore comments in a string based on compiler design?

Tags: python, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

I want to ignore every comment like  `{ comments }` and `//   comments`.
I have a pointer named **peek** that checks my string **character by character**. I know how to ignore newlines, tabs, and spaces but I don't know how to ignore **comments**.

```
string =  """  beGIn west   WEST north//comment1 \n
north       north west East east south\n
// comment west\n
{\n
    comment\n
}\n end
"""

tokens = []
tmp = ''

for i, peek in enumerate(string.lower()):
    if peek == ' ' or peek == '\n':
        tokens.append(tmp)
        # ignoing WS's and comments
        if(len(tmp)>0): 
            print(tmp)

        tmp = ''
    
    else:
        tmp += peek
```

Here is my result:

```
begin
west
west
north//
comment1
north
north
west
east
east
south
{
comment2
}
end
```

As you see spaces are ignored but comments aren't.

How can I get a result like below?

```
begin
west
west
north
north
north
west
east
east
south
end
```

Comment: For a basic implementation, check if the current character is `{`, if it is, ignore everything until the closing `}`, then proceed as usual.

Comment: @AndrewMcClement That's the problem I don't know how to implement this step, I don't know if I should use regex or something else, another problem is if the input string has multi-line comments, what I should do.

Comment: simply use `if peek == '{': skip = True elif peek == '}': skip = False` and run rest of `if/else` in `if not skip: ... your code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use global variable `skip = False` and set it `True` when you get `{` and set `False` when you get `}` and the rest of your `if/else` run in `if not skip:`

```
string =  """  beGIn west   WEST north//comment1 \n
north       north west East east south\n
// comment west\n
{\n
    comment\n
}\n end
"""

tokens = []
tmp = ''
skip = False

for i, peek in enumerate(string.lower()):

    if peek == '{':
        skip = True
    elif peek == '}':
        skip = False
    elif not skip:

        if peek == ' ' or peek == '\n':
            tokens.append(tmp)
            # ignoing WS's and comments
            if(len(tmp)>0): 
                print(tmp)
            tmp = ''
        else:
            tmp += peek
```

Because you may have nested `{ { } }` like

```
{\n
    { comment1 }\n
    comment2\n
    { comment3 }\n
}\n
```

so better use `skip` to count `{` `}`

```
string =  """  beGIn west   WEST north//comment1 \n
north       north west East east south\n
// comment west\n
{\n
    { comment1 }\n
    comment2\n
    { comment3 }\n
}\n end
"""

tokens = []
tmp = ''
skip = 0

for i, peek in enumerate(string.lower()):

    if peek == '{':
        skip += 1
    elif peek == '}':
        skip -= 1
    elif not skip:  # elif skip == 0:

        if peek == ' ' or peek == '\n':
            tokens.append(tmp)
            # ignoing WS's and comments
            if(len(tmp)>0): 
                print(tmp)
            tmp = ''
        else:
            tmp += peek
```

But maybe it would be better to get all as `tokens` and later filter `tokens`. But I skip this idea.

---

**EDIT:**

Version using Python module [sly](https://github.com/dabeaz/sly) which works similar to C/C++ tools `lex`/`yacc`

Regex for `MULTI_LINE_COMMENT` I found in other tool for building parsers - `lark`:

[syntax for multiline comments](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/issues/78)

```
from sly import Lexer, Parser

class MyLexer(Lexer):
    # Create it befor defining regex for Tokens
    tokens = { NAME, ONE_LINE_COMMENT, MULTI_LINE_COMMENT }

    ignore = ' \t'

    # Tokens
    NAME = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
    ONE_LINE_COMMENT = '\/\/.*'
    MULTI_LINE_COMMENT = '{(.|\n)*}'

    # Ignored pattern
    ignore_newline = r'\n+'

    # Extra action for newlines
    def ignore_newline(self, t):
        self.lineno += t.value.count('\n')

    # Work with errors
    def error(self, t):
        print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
        self.index += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    text =  """  beGIn west   WEST north//comment1 
north       north west East east south
// comment west
{
    { comment1 }
    comment2
    { comment3 }
}
 end
"""
    
    lexer = MyLexer()
    tokens = lexer.tokenize(text)
    for item in tokens:
        print(item.type, ':', item.value)
```

Result:

```
NAME : beGIn
NAME : west
NAME : WEST
NAME : north
ONE_LINE_COMMENT : //comment1 
NAME : north
NAME : north
NAME : west
NAME : East
NAME : east
NAME : south
ONE_LINE_COMMENT : // comment west
MULTI_LINE_COMMENT : {
    { comment1 }
    comment2
    { comment3 }
}
NAME : end
```

Comment: maybe it would be better to get all as `tokens` and later filter `tokens`. But I skip this idea.

Comment: the lexical analyzer uses peek as a pointer, when peek faces a letter it moves forward until it faces a non-letter or digit, this is how a token is made, then we have to check if the token is in the symbol table or not. I have your idea in my mind too, I'm not sure if it's true or not, but suppose we have a string like `start west// north`, if we tokenize we will have `start, west, //, north` as tokens. I don't think if there is a compiler that acts like that.

Comment: what do you think about ignoring comments that start with `//`. the peek checks one character at a time, but now we have to check two characters and it has to ignore characters until the end of the line!!!! @furas

Comment: I think compiler may tokenize as two elements `west`, `// north` and then it can simply remove `// north`. I never write compiler from scratch - I was rather use C/C++ tools `lex`/`yacc` or Python module `ply` or [sly](https://github.com/dabeaz/sly) which works similar to `lex`/`yacc` . But I never tried to tokenize comments.

Comment: I added example with module `sly` and it can recognize `ONE_LINE_COMMENT` and `MULTI_LINE_COMMENT`. It simply use `regex` for this.

Comment: BTW: if you use text in `""" """` then you don't have to add `\n`

Comment: yeah, that's true I thought I could ignore comments starting with `//` with  `\n`. I have to implement a predictive parser. don't you think its better to read the input from a text file instead of using `""" """` in the main program? @furas

Comment: my purpose is to ignore all these comments and spaces and separate actual tokens as the peek moves forward.

Comment: using `""" """` you can simpler share code with others on Stackoverflow or other forums - so we can simply copy and test it. Reading from file you would have to add this file to question - and this can make problem. And when code will work correctly then you can  add `string = open(...).read()`.

Answer (score 0):

@furas answer works, but to make it count newlines properly, use the `_` decorator:

```
@_('{(.|\n)*}')
def MULTILINE_COMMENT(self, t):
    self.lineno += t.value.count('\n')
    return t
```